# Getting "No such file or directory/" error while running command in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to load the database as part of the image creation using dockerfile.  At the end, I am trying to load the data to the mysql database by adding a shell file as part of the docker entry point.

```
COPY ./scripts/initdb.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

the `initdb.sh` has the following content

```
mysql -u root -p<root_password> <database_name> < /data/dump.sql
```

The problem is when the file is executed I am getting the following error:

> : No such file or directory/initdb.sh: line 1: /data/dump.sql

I have checked the following

- the files exists in the correct directory
- the permission are  proper (`-rwxr-xr-x`)
- changed the permission thru `RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.sh`

but, nothing seems to be working, am sure there is a something simple I am missing.

Comment: You should be able to just put the `dump.sql` file directly in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`; does that work better?  Is there a `#!/bin/sh` or similar line at the start of the shell script?  Have you double-checked DOS vs. Unix line endings?

Comment: Perfect ! Genius !  there were 2 problems - a) the #!/bin/sh was missing and then when transferred from windows, the ^M did sneak in. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following command:

```
sudo docker compose exec -it companydb sh -c "mysql -u company -p company < docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/company.sql"
```